# In joomla instead of Domain Name, IP address shows in address bar(URL rewrite rules)!

Tags: ubuntu, joomla, web

At our college we have implemented our website and hosting it on our own servers. The server is Apache and OS is Ubuntu. My colleague posed me this query. He says the httpd.conf file has to be edited for rewriting domain name.
Our website is This-> http://cityengineeringcollege.ac.in
What should be there in that file to display correct domain name. In joomla global configuration even though we chose to use URL rewriting in SEO settings the URL is not being rewritten. We are directing web page requests from 202.62.95.50 to 202.62.95.51.
P.S
The .htaccess file has following rewrite section

```
RewriteBase /city

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
```

The config file /etc/apache2/httpd.conf has the following code

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.cityengineeringcollege.ac.in
DocumentRoot /var/www
....
</VirtualHost>
```

My Question is is the document root correct like i think it should be /var/www/city and The file /etc/hosts has( as its first line)

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
```

which i think should have the server name as an alias like

```
127.0.0.1 localhost cityengineeringcollege.ac.in
cityengineeringcollege.ac.in localhost
```

Is this correct? The thing is i am eager to set the things right and we can work on this only during office hours(9-5). We have tried out a variety of things like searching for ServerName in /etc/apache2 folder using grep and inserting the line

```
ServerName www.cityengineeringcollege.ac.in
```

everywhere it is found. Is www required there? We have a file called city inside sites_available which is a clone of the file 000-default and that file is linked with sites_enabled using

```
sudo a2ensite city
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Joomla problem. Joomla uses relative URLs for everything so the domain name is controlled by either a redirect in your htaccess file, an extension that is not properly coded, or the server itself. If it did this in Drupal as well, then I would say it's a server configuration problem.

Easy test - upload index.html to the root directory you have Joomla installed in, then access that file. If the domain redirects to the IP address then it's most likely a server configuration problem.

Comment: I browsed through httpd.conf and found that inside the VirtualHost tag the ServerName is there after <Directory />...<Directory>. Does the order ServerName then ServerAlias then ServerAdmin then DocumentRoot then <Directory /> have to be followed? My friend forgot to restart the server so i could not say if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the cause is, it's most likely a part of your index page. But when I visit it, my browser is being redirected. This means that somewhere in your joomla code it's issuing the following:

```
header("Location: http://202.62.95.51/city//");
```

which is causing the website to be forwarded to the IP address. If you haven't modified any of the code and only used Joomla, it's most likely a function in joomla since it's definitely coming from PHP.

[image: Browser network trace]

Comment: He told me he used drupal and developed another site with address http://202.62.95.51/dcity// and the problem persists with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

My sys admin said the problem has been solved. He did not elaborate exactly all the steps but said that the RewriteBase in .htaccess has been changed back to

```
RewriteBase /
```

And DocumentRoot was changed to /www/city and it worked after that. Now he is busy making dcity that i had mentioned in one comment developed using drupal accessible. I had forgot to mention that our server uses name based virtual hosting. There is another site(domain name) that we are hosting along with our own. I would like to thank all the answerers who have helped in one way or other.